# WPF: How should I refactor this C# project?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, refactoring

**THE PROBLEM**

I have created a monster. 169 Lists, 169 CheckBoxes, 169 if statements. This sucks and I want to refactor it.

Here is some pseudocode to demonstrate:

**XAML**

```
<checkbox Name="CheckBox1"...
// etc
<checkbox Name="CheckBox169"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
List<ulong> masterList = big_array_of_ulongs;
List<ulong> list1 = array_of_ulongs;
List<ulong> list2 = array_of_ulongs;
// etc
List<ulong> list169 = array_of_ulongs;

// if listX and masterList contain a duplicate element...
// ...listX's corresponding CheckBox is checked.
if (masterList.Any(x => list1.Contains(x))
{
  CheckBox1.IsPressed = true;
}

if(masterList.Any(x => list2.Contains(x))
{
  CheckBox2.IsPressed = true;
}
// etc
if(masterList.Any(x => list169.Contains(x))
{
  CheckBox169.IsPressed = true;
}
```

**SOLUTION?**

I attempted to reduce this mess to a couple of functions but I can't find a way to associate each list with its corresponding CheckBox.

Help with that would be much appreciated or if you have a better idea please share, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a perfect case for an `ItemTemplate` and `ItemsControl`. How close is this code to real?

Comment: The code is actually identical. Thank you for the suggestions! I will read into it now.

Comment: Tracked down a tutorial, if it helps:

http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is identical code and you want a quick refactor...

```
for(int i = 1; i < 170; ++i)
{
 String tempName1 = "list" + i;
 List<ulong> temp1 = (List<ulong>)this.GetType().GetProperty(tempName1).GetValue(this, null);
 if (masterList.Any(x => temp1.Contains(x))
 {
  String tempName2 = "CheckBox" + i;
  CheckBox temp2 = (CheckBox)this.GetType().GetProperty(tempName2).GetValue(this, null);
  temp2.IsPressed = true;
 }
}
```

Use it if your looking to make the code easier to read, its less efficient but really shouldn't matter with only 169 iterations

Comment: (List<ulong>)this.GetType().GetProperty(tempName1).GetValue(this, null);


Throws a NullReferenceException.

Comment: This works in general, the error is going to be specific to something your doing, debug to find where it gets the exception. Does it get it the first time it runs, or the last, etc.